# Simple way to find the trace or the bound of the trace of $ ABA^T$?

Tags: trace

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are square matrices, is there any simple way to find the
trace or the bound of the trace of $ABA^T$?
Thanks.

$B$ has the form of 
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a_{1} & a_{2} & a_{3} \\
0 & 0 & a_{1} & a_{2} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & a_{1} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
$A$ is unrestricted.

Comment: What is the matrix $A'$ in relation to $A$?

Comment: Suppose we have the special case: $B + B' = C^{2}$ for some self-adjoint operator $C$.  Then 
$$
\mbox{tr }(A C^2 A') = \mbox{tr }(A C C' A') = \mbox{the Frobenius norm of $AC$},
$$
and the latter norm overestimates $\mbox{tr }(A B A')$ approximately (and sometimes exactly) by a factor of $2$.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for lower and upper bound for the trace.

Answer (score 1):

One bound you might like (using the Cauchy Schwartz inequality on the Hilbert Schmidt inner product) is
$$
|tr(ABA')| = |tr(A'AB)| \leq tr(A'A)\sqrt{tr(B'B)}
$$

Comment: Thanks. Is there any lower bound for the trace?

Comment: See my latest edit

Comment: Thanks a lot! But this is not the lower bound of tr(ABA′), I am just wondering is there any formula such as a<tr(ABA′)<b, b is given by you, is it possible to find a? Many thanks!

Comment: Yes it does. In particular, saying $|x|<a$ is the same as saying $-a<x<a$.

Comment: Thanks. I did realized that it is absolute value. But this bound is quite loose in the sense that zero could be included. Is there any chance to have a lower and upper bound with the same sign, say if tr(ABA′)>0? Thanks

Comment: We would need to know more about $B$. For example, there will be a lower bound if $B$ is positive definite. You might get a more useful result from this site if you make a post detailing what it is that you're using these inequalities for anyway

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have revised my question for an explicit formula of $B$.

Comment: You should have made a new post instead of revising this one